# Monokai pro theme interfering with Ruby extension by Peng Lv on VScode

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, syntax, syntax-highlighting

hope this question is not stupid, I'm going straight to the point.
I recently decided to use the Monokai Pro default theme on my VScode because it looks a lot nicer. Lately I have been coding in Ruby.

This is a screenshot of a random piece of code, with the Monokai Pro theme, where I wrote random things just to show you the colors:

[image: Ruby with the Monokai Pro default theme]

Seems pretty cool, Monokai Pro has a syntax highlight for Ruby, at least it seems.

I then decided to download this [Ruby extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rebornix.Ruby) which is the most downloaded one for Ruby. It provides language support, and when downloaded, downloads a dependence, which is [this one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wingrunr21.vscode-ruby). This extension provides syntax highlighting for Ruby. Here it is, when using the Monokai Pro theme:

[image: Ruby with the Monokai Pro theme and the VScode Ruby extension]

As you might see, they seem to interfere a little bit.Symbols are in fact not orange anymore, and their color became purple, just like numbers and booleans.

The VScode Ruby extension is however designed in order to color symbols a different way than other objects, as you can see here:

[image: Ruby code without the Monakai Pro theme but with the VScode Ruby extension]

My question is, is there a way I can use the Monokai Pro theme and download the [first extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rebornix.Ruby), without having to use the [dependence extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wingrunr21.vscode-ruby) that seems to interfere with the Monokai theme. I think the Monokai theme already has syntax highlight for Ruby and that is enough.

Comment: the theme does interfere with the language support. Most likely the language support you added implements things like semantic highlighting

Comment: Didn't the theme itself provided semantic highlighting?

Comment: a theme just assigns colors to scopes determined by the TextMate grammar of the language

Comment: Is there a way I can make the symbols back orange even with the language support?

Comment: you can try disabling semantic highlighting